# Create a PDF from a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Is there any way or any libraries to create a PDF from a UIView preserving the text ie with the text selectable. I have have tried the following but the clarity is compromised as it is rendered as a bitmap.

```
+ (NSData *)pdfDataOfScrollView:(UITableView *)scrollView
{
  NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

  UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, scrollView.bounds, nil);
  UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
  CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

  [scrollView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

  // remove PDF rendering context
  UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
  return pdfData;
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/iclems/iOS-htmltopdf.  This library may be useful to you

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library to create PDF [Link](https://cocoapods.org/?q=pdf).

Using above library you can generate PDF from below code.

```
func generatePDF() {
    let v1 = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0,y: 0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0))
    let v2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0,y: 0, width: 100.0, height: 200.0))
    let v3 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0,y: 0, width: 100.0, height: 200.0))
    v1.backgroundColor = .red
    v1.contentSize = CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 200.0)
    v2.backgroundColor = .green
    v3.backgroundColor = .blue

    let dst = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory().stringByAppendingString("/sample1.pdf"))
    // outputs as Data
    do {
        let data = try PDFGenerator.generated(by: [v1, v2, v3])
        data.write(to: dst, options: .atomic)
    } catch (let error) {
        print(error)
    }

    // writes to Disk directly.
    do {
        try PDFGenerator.generate([v1, v2, v3], to: dst)    
    } catch (let error) {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this code**

```
NSMutableData *pdfData=[NSMutableData data];
CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 792); // letter sized paper, adjust as needed

UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, bounds, nil);
CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
[aView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
[bView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext2];

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```